# Does SetLookAt requires the normals to be multiplied by the inverse transponse matrix?

Tags: javascript, math, 3d

When I use SetLookAt in from the matrix library used in the book "WebGL Programing Guide?, then is it necessary to multiply the normals by the transpose inverse matrix of the viewmatrix before lighting calculations occur, even when the viewmatrix only contains the transformation applied by the SetLookAt method and no other transformations?

Comment: There is no `SetLookAt` function in WebGL. Please clarify what framework you're actually asking about.

Comment: It's the library used in the book WebGL Programming Guide, the code can be found here: https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/home/downloads
SetLookAt is located in the file cuon-matrix.js

Answer (score 0):

Someone who's good at math will hopefully come by and give a better answer but I thought the reason to use the transpose inverse was because it somehow handles the case where there is non-uniform scaling applied to the matrix. So if you're not scaling you don't need the inverse transpose and if you're not rotating you don't need anything

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/126482-Why-the-normal-vector-is-transformed-by-modelview-matrix-s-inverse